# React - When creating a new object inside an array, it outputs undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I created an array with objects that I use to style different parts of the components, the problem I started when I tried to create a new object inside this array.

Please pay attention to the `BackSideBarIcon` property, after I added this new property I get an error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'FontWeight' of undefined**

Before adding the `BackSideBarIcon` property, everything worked fine for me

```
import { faHashtag } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const GradientThemes = [
    {
        BackSideBarIcon: true,
    },

    {
        SideBar: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(66, 116, 131, 1) 0%, rgba(69, 75, 88, 1) 100%)",
        PageContent: "linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(65,116,130,1) 0%, #353a4f 80%)",
        RadioButtonBackground: "linear-gradient(40deg, #51adff, #10f4a0)",
        RadioButtonBorderColor: "1px solid #33b7de",
        MarginLeft: "25px",

        FontStyle: {
            FontWeight: "400",
            FontSize: '15px',
        },

        TextColors: {
            UserName: {
                UserNameColor: "#eaecf1",
            },
            SideBarTextColors: {
                titleColor: "#eceaeab3",
                itemColor: "#d1d6e2",
            }
        },

        IconStyle: {
            IconTitle: faHashtag,
            IconColor: "#ffffff3b",
            ThemePalette: "#9bb9c5",
        }
    },
].map((item) => {
    return {

        BackSideBarIcon: item.BackSideBarIcon,

        SideBar: item.SideBar,
        PageContent: item.PageContent,
        RadioButtonBackground: item.RadioButtonBackground,
        RadioButtonBorderColor: item.RadioButtonBorderColor,
        MarginLeft: item.MarginLeft,

        // Font Style
        FontWeight: item.FontStyle.FontWeight,
        FontSize: item.FontStyle.FontSize,

        // Text Style
        UserNameColor: item.TextColors.UserName.UserNameColor,
        TitleColor: item.TextColors.SideBarTextColors.titleColor,
        ItemColor: item.TextColors.SideBarTextColors.itemColor,

        // Icons Style
        IconTitle: item.IconStyle.IconTitle,
        IconColor: item.IconStyle.IconColor,
        ThemePalette: item.IconStyle.ThemePalette
    }
}
)

export default GradientThemes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code triggers this error when you try to access `item.FontStyle.FontWeight` of the first item in your array. Because it does not have a `FontStyle` attribute, you wind up trying to access the `FontWeight` attribute of `undefined`:

```
const firstItem = {BackSideBarIcon: true};
console.log(firstItem.FontStyle.FontWeight); // triggers your error
```

To solve this, you need to handle undefined properties, like so:

```
yourItems.map((item) => {
  return {
    BackSideBarIcon: item.BackSideBarIcon,
    
    // Here, we use the value of the item's FontStyle, or 
    // an empty object if FontStyle is undefined. 
    FontWeight: (item.FontStyle || {}).FontWeight,
  };
});
```

Keep in mind that, in `GradientThemes`, the `FontWeight` property will remain undefined for every item that doesn't have a `FontStyle` to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question, but after changing the code to the one you suggested, it now gives a new error that 'FontSize' of undefined

Comment: You need to do the `(object || {}).property` trick (or some other way of dealing with undefined values) wherever you access nested properties